# Object literal constructor

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, object-literal

I am looking for a way to modify an object that was defined by a literal without passing it into another function.

example:

```
let o = {a:1,b:2}
console.log(o.a===3)
```

i thought when i define an object using a literal the the Object constructor would be called, so i did override `Object.prototype.constructor` but it only gets called when i do `new Object({a:1,b:2})`

question in simpler terms can anyone make `a=3` without passing the object o to a function or a proxy or using `o.a=3` or `with` keyword, where `o` is defined using an object literal?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the specific issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: @vlaz making every javascript object observable, without having to pass it to another function

Comment: *I want Javascript to change a value, but I don't want to specify where that value is.* That is basically what you're telling us?

Comment: @Delta As the question stands it makes no sense and therefore can't be answered. Please expand it and explain the specific requirements you are mentioning. Why can't you pass it to a function? Why can't you just assign a value?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i want to do it implicitly, by overriding a constructor for example, but i can't find a constructor of an object literal

Comment: It's simply not possible. There is no constructor of an object literal. You can create objects in different ways: Via an object literal *or* via a constructor function *or* via Object.create

Comment: @DanielHilgarth thank you just wanted to make sure its impossible, i would chose that as an answer.

Comment: Just posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply not possible.
There is no constructor of an object literal.
You can create objects in different ways:

- via an object literal *or*
- via a constructor function *or*
- via `Object.create`

Also, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 2):

Just do `o.a=3;` and console log `o`:

```js
let o = {a:1,b:2};
o.a=3;
console.log(o);
```

Currently you are doing `o.a===3` which will return `Boolean` value instead of overwriting the value of property `a`.

You also cannot do `o.a=3` inside `console.log()` because `o.a=3` will return the assigned value which is `3` but it will still change the property `a` of `o` to `3`.

```js
let o = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
//won't print o but changes o.a to 3
console.log(o.a = 3);
```

Comment: come on, jokes aside, i know its a valid answer but i meant without having accessing property after the object was constructed

Comment: I don't get what you'd like to acomplish

Answer (score 0):

> question in simpler terms can anyone make a=3 without passing the object o to a function or a proxy?

```
  o.a = 3;
```

> I am looking for a way to modify an object that was defined by a literal without passing it into another function.

Thats impossible, cause if it would be possible you could break every piece of javascript. And that would be terrible.

*Oh wait, this is JS...*

```
 with({ get o() { return { a: 3 }; }, set o(v) {} }) {

  o = {a:1,b:2};
  console.log(o.a===3) // true

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve could be done if `o.a` holds a reference to the variable `a` - which unfortunately only works the way you'd like for variables that are *passed by reference*. Primitive types like `String`, `Number` and `Boolean` though, are passed *by value*.

Check the examples below:

```js
var a = 1;

var o = { a: a };

a = 2;

console.log(o.a, a);
```

It also doesn't help to use an Object constructor like `new Number()` because that does return a reference to an object (which is *passed by reference* as you'd need), but assigning a new value to it reading the value still returns a primitive (which is, again, passed by *value*):

```js
var a = new Number(1);

var o = { a: a.valueOf() };

a = Number(2);

console.log(o.a, a);
```

If you pass something that is naturally passed by reference, your expectation is fulfilled:

```js
var a = [ 1 ]

var o = { a: a }

a[0] = 2

console.log(o.a[0])
```